# Opening multiple Fancybox galleries via manual links

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've attempted to convert the solution offered in [How do I open fancybox via manual call for a gallery in the html not via the jquery options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835849/how-do-i-open-fancybox-via-manual-call-for-a-gallery-in-the-html-not-via-the-jqu) in order to apply it to several galleries, but can't get it to function correctly.

What I have is several links with the following attributes:

```
<a href="#" class="open-album" data-open-id="album-1">Album 1</a>
<a href="#" class="open-album" data-open-id="album-2">Album 2</a>
```

etc.

These are supposed to apply to their respective Fancybox-enabled albums, for example:

```
 <a href="#" class="image-show" rel="album-1"><img src="#" /></a>
 <a href="#" class="image-show" rel="album-1"><img src="#" /></a>
 <a href="#" class="image-show" rel="album-1"><img src="#" /></a>
```

and

```
 <a href="#" class="image-show" rel="album-2"><img src="#" /></a>
 <a href="#" class="image-show" rel="album-2"><img src="#" /></a>
 <a href="#" class="image-show" rel="album-2"><img src="#" /></a>
```

Fancybox looks for the `.image-show` class, and works fine when the images themselves are clicked.

The following jQuery code is supposed to link the album titles to the 1st image in their respective albums:

```
 $('.open-album').click(function(e) {
    var el, id = $(this.element).data('open-id');
    if(id){
        el = $('.image-show[rel=' + id + ']:eq(0)');
        e.preventDefault();
        el.click();
    }
});
```

As you can see, the goal was to obtain the `data-open-id` from the album title and use it to open the first Fancybox item with the value as its `rel` attribute. Alas, it doesn't work. Any ideas on what could be going wrong? Your help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are binding the selector `.image-show` to fancybox, aren't you?

```
$(".image-show").fancybox();
```

if so, the issue with your code is that `$(this.element)` should be used [within fancybox callbacks only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11958689/1055987), but since you are using a regular jQuery method ( `.click()` ) then you should refer to the current element like `$(this)`

```
$('.open-album').click(function(e) {
    var el, id = $(this).data('open-id');
    if(id){
        el = $('.image-show[rel=' + id + ']:eq(0)');
        e.preventDefault();
        el.click();
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m8ynV/)**